# Solve an Inequality using Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, numerical-value

I would like to solve a simple inequality 0 < 2 A + B <= 1 with 0 < B < 1 and 0<A<1/2 , using Mathematica.

I tried using the command `FindInstance` but I am able set a constraint on only one variable. Hence I get negative values for the other variable. Could you please suggest an alternate way of achieving the same?
My attempts:

`` In[283]:= ClearAll["Global`*"] ``

`In[288]:= FindInstance[0 < 2 A + B <= 1 && 0 < B < 1/2 , {A, B}, Reals, 10]`

```
  B -> 259/4005}, {A -> 518/4005, B -> 39/203}, {A -> -(868/4005), 
  B -> 373/759}, {A -> -(364/4005), B -> 56/159}, {A -> 151/801, 
  B -> 16/203}, {A -> 1789/4005, B -> 23/474}, {A -> 201/445, 
  B -> 47/1046}, {A -> 269/801, B -> 263/801}, {A -> -(104/4005), 
  B -> 50/113}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `FindInstance[{0 < 2 a + b <= 1, 0 < b < 1/2, 0 < a < 1/2}, {a, 
  b}, Reals, 10]`

Comment: "To solve an inequality" and "to find a few values that satisfy inequalities" are slightly different different problems to me.  Can you clarify? @cvgmt's comment seems the natural way to extend your code to your full problem, but you seem to say you couldn't add the inequality for `A`. Maybe you made a simple typo or other mistake?

Comment: Firstly, I didn't know how to include the second constraint in ``FindInstance``and secondly, I needed to find a few values that satisfy the given inequality as well. So cvgmt reply answers both my questions.

Answer (score 2):

`Reduce` solves the inequalities

```
Reduce[{0 < 2 a + b <= 1, 0 < b < 1/2, 0 < a <1/2}, {a, b}, Reals]
(*(0 < a <= 1/4 && 0 < b < 1/2) || (1/4 < a < 1/2 && 0 < b <= 1 - 2 a)*)
```